# Is it possible to replace glutMainLoop() with simple loop?

Tags: opengl, glut

Is it possible to replace `glutMainLoop()` with simple loop ( e.g. `while` or `for` ) and in this loop just call all callbacks?

I have done this and picture is displaying fine but window ( in which is picture displayed ) is not responding ( can not move  it ).

Does `glutMainLoop()` call more than callbacks?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using FreeGLUT, you can use [`glutMainLoopEvent`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#EventProcessing). It does one cycle of processing of the event loop, so you can call it in a loop.

```
while(...)
{
  glutMainLoopEvent();
  //do other stuff.
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

`glutMainLoop` also handles all window communicates, so if you want to replace it, you will either need to use a (another) library for that, or write system specific code resolving communicates from operating system. There are a lot of examples on the Internet, though, at least for MS Windows.

[Here's MSDN arcticle about Win32 main function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Comment: The question is not about Win32.

Answer (score 1):

> Does glutMainLoop() call more than callbacks?

Yes, its responsible for the whole event management, like getting the events from your graphics system. It then calls the callbacks with the event data.

If you want to do your own event processing, don't use GLUT. There are other frameworks, that give you a lower level access to events and expect you to do all event dispatching. Have a look at GLFW and SDL.